# vim-latex: how to do automatic carriage return when linewidth reached?

Tags: vim, latex

When I was using emacs with the auctex plugin, there was a mode called auto-fill-mode which would automatically insert a carriage return whenever the linewidth was reached, instead of creating one really long line as you carry on typing.

Is there something similar in vim-latex?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look up the `textwidth` option.

```
:set tw=80
```

You can also reformat existing text with respect to this option using the `gq` command.

Comment: That didn't work. The problem is that when I try to navigate up and down lines with j and k, it will skip entire paragraphs instead of single lines (this is because one line of text is spanning multiple lines)

Comment: @Eddy : `nnoremap j gj` and `nnoremap k gk` inside your `.vimrc`/`_vimrc` should fix your problem.